# Python - Decodificar mensaje enviado por un cliente websocket

Tags: python, websocket

Estoy implementando un servidor websocket en Python desde cero (un reto que me propuesto a mi mismo). Ya es capaz de recibir los mensajes provenientes del API WebSocket de Javascript, pero no logro codificar el mensaje recibido en el servidor. Por ejemplo: para el mensaje **Hola mundo** enviado por el cliente, recibo esto:

```
b'\x81\x8aX\x1a\xfc\xaa\x10u\x90\xcbxw\x89\xc4<u'
```

Los bytes recibidos no serán los mismos por cada **Hola mundo** enviado, pero segun he leido todas estas variaciones de bytes apuntan al propio **Hola mundo** cuando son decodificadas.

Si hago un eco (o sea, enviar lo mismo que recibo), el cliente Javascript responde apropiadamente con un **Hola mundo**, considerando el ejemplo anterior.

Mi pregunta: ¿cómo puedo decodificar el string recibido, y como puedo codificar cualquier otro string para enviarlo de vuelta?

Este es el código del servidor:

```
import socket, ssl, threading, hashlib, base64, os
Mimes = {
    'html': 'text/html',
    'css': 'text/css',
    'js': 'text/javascript',
    'png': 'image/png',
    'jpg': 'image/jpg',
    'gif': 'image/gif',
    'svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
    'mp4': 'video/mp4',
    'ttf': 'font/ttf',
    'rar': 'application/x-rar-compressed',
    'zip': 'application/zip',
    'exe': 'application/x-msdownload',
}

#ManejarCliente
def ManejarCliente (Cliente, Direccion):
    try:
        #Recibiendo mensaje
        Entradas = b''
        while True:
            Parcial = Cliente.recv (4096)
            Entradas += Parcial
            if len (Parcial) < 4096: break
        Entradas = Entradas.split (b'\r\n\r\n') [0].decode ().split ('\r\n')
        URL = Entradas [0].split (' ') [1] [1:] or 'Indice.html'
        Respuesta = []
        try: ClaveWS = next (E for E in Entradas if 'Sec-WebSocket-Key' in E)
        except StopIteration: ClaveWS = None
        #Si existe el header "Sec-WebSocket-Key" entonces es una conexión websocket
        if ClaveWS:
            ClaveWS = ClaveWS.split (': ') [-1].encode () + b'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'
            ClaveWS = hashlib.sha1 (ClaveWS).digest ()
            ClaveWS = base64.b64encode (ClaveWS)
            Cliente.send (b'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching protocol\r\n')
            Cliente.send (b'Upgrade: websocket\r\n')
            Cliente.send (b'Connection: upgrade\r\n')
            Cliente.send (b'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ' + ClaveWS + b'\r\n\r\n')
            ClientesWS.append (Cliente)
            #Recibir mensajes WS
            while True:
                print ('Listo para recibir mensajes WS')
                EntradasWS = b''
                while True:
                    ParcialWS = Cliente.recv (1024)
                    EntradasWS += ParcialWS
                    if len (ParcialWS) < 1024: break
                Cliente.send (EntradasWS) #Un eco
                if False: break #Cuando se cierra el navegador se envian unos bytes específicos para cerrar la conexión WS
        #Si no existe entonces es una conexión http
        else:
            try:
                with open (URL, 'rb') as Archivo:
                    Extension = URL.split ('.') [-1] if '.' in URL else None
                    Cliente.send (b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
                    Cliente.send (f"Content-Type: { Mimes [Extension] if Extension in Mimes else 'application/octet-stream' }\r\n".encode ())
                    Cliente.send (f"Content-Length: { os.path.getsize (URL) }\r\n".encode ())
                    Cliente.send (b'\r\n')
                    Lectura = Archivo.read (10240)
                    Cliente.send (Lectura)
                    while Lectura:
                        Lectura = Archivo.read (10240)
                        Cliente.send (Lectura)
                    Cliente.send (b'\r\n')
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass #No implementado por ahora
    except Exception as Err:
        print (Err)
    finally:
        Cliente.close ()

ContextoSSL = ssl.SSLContext (ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ContextoSSL.load_cert_chain ('SSL/server.crt', 'SSL/server.key')
PreServidor = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Servidor = ContextoSSL.wrap_socket (PreServidor)
PreServidor.close ()
Servidor.bind (('0.0.0.0', 443))
Servidor.listen ()
while True:
    try:
        Cliente, Direccion = Servidor.accept ()
        threading.Thread (target = ManejarCliente, args = [Cliente, Direccion [0]]).start ()
    except Exception as Err:
        print (Err)
```

Y esto es código Javascript para testear:

```
let WS = new WebSocket ('wss://127.0.0.1')
WS.onopen = function () {
    alert ('Abierto')
}
WS.onclose = function () {
    alert ('Cerrado')
}
WS.onerror = function () {
    alert ('Error')
}
WS.onmessage = function (e) {
    alert (`Mensaje: ${ e.data }`)
}
document.body.on ('click', function () {
    WS.send ('Hola mundo')
})
```

Comment: Si publicaras el código podríamos decirte donde está el problema y cual es la solución.

Comment: Vale, editaré la pregunta y lo publicaré

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta. Por cierto @CandidMoe, este es el mismo servidor de la pregunta que hice duplicada, preguntando como podía escuchar conexiones WS. Y ya las escucha perfectamente, pero no se que hacer con lo que recibo, solo hacer ecos :-)